# API add Location Header and 302

Tags: php, xml, api

I've written an API using a simple but fairly long query string request.
The requester can designate an XML or HTML response.

The query is received and the data is processed. The HTML simply echos back a response. In order to avoid redundant code, I use a JavaScript redirect to open and process the XML. That looks like this:

```
$QString = '';
foreach($XMLItems as $key => $value)
{
   $QString .= $key.'^'.$value.'|';
}
$QString = substr($QString,0,-1);
Redirect('XMLProcess.php?Q='.$QString);
```

Redirect() is a simple function that runs javascript:

```
function Redirect($n)
{
    die("<script type=\"text/javascript\">window.location='$n';</script>");
}
```

The XML construction looks like this:

```
<?php
    $dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
    header ("Content-Type:text/xml");
    $QArray = explode('|',$_REQUEST[Q]);
    foreach($QArray as $value)
    {
       $x = explode('^',$value);
       $XMLItems[$x[0]] = $x[1];
    }

    $root = $dom->createElement("Data");
    $dom->appendChild($root);
    foreach($XMLItems as $key => $value)
    {
       $key = $dom->createElement($key);
       $root->appendChild($key);
       $variable = $dom->createTextNode($value);
       $key->appendChild($variable);
    }
    echo $dom->saveXML();
?>
```

I'm pretty ignorant as far as API's and what someone may be using on the receiving end. I have a client who is asking for a 302 redirect and location header. I am assuming my Redirect() function may be throwing his software off, but I don't really know. Of course, I cannot redirect to the XML file immediately, as the incoming data needs to be processed first. So I am trying to wrap my mind around what the client needs without duplicating the processing in a second file. And, since I am in the dark, the Redirect may not be the problem, anyway.

Comment: Just before the die, emit a `header('Location: sameurlasthejavascript');`. This tells the browser to do a redirect and will be honored by virtually every client. Thw Javascript body may remain as a fallback.

Comment: I'm afraid that's going to fail, which is why I used the JavaScript. In the processing before the redirect, there are a couple of includes and one of those includes requests data from an AS400 API.

Comment: I dont quite follow, but if you are saying it wont woek bevause theres already sent data, then use ob_start and friends to capture and output in the correct order.

Comment: Never even considered that. Still not sure that would be an answer, though

Comment: Ran out of edit time on previous comment. Never even considered that. I have used it so seldom. Still not sure that would be an answer, though, although I'm not saying it isn't. There are 2 problems here. One is that some clients expect a header (Content-Type:text/xml), while others use a client that is going to ignore that anyway. The parent script has an HTML doctype which will conflict with the XML header if I include the XML markup in the script. So, would I be able to avoid that conflict using ob_start? In other words will it buffer that HTML doctype info?

Comment: I'd need to see the specific code to answer that question, but it sounds like you're having to make all kinds of detours to facilitate multi-mode output. Like I said in my answer, this is feeling pretty janky. Best to just refactor the calculation part out to its own helper, and let the HTML and XML front-ends emit whatever is relevant for them. Doing that avoids all this redirect and ob_ business.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To emit a 302 Redirect (or indeed any status code), you need to use [`header`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php). Per the docs:

> The second special case is the "Location:" header. Not only does it send this header back to the browser, but it also returns a REDIRECT (302) status code to the browser unless the 201 or a 3xx status code has already been set.

which would be implemented like:

```
function Redirect($n)
{
    header("Location: $n");
    exit(0);
}
```

As noted in the comments, since your script is emitting output prior to the invocation of `Redirect`, you'll need to use [`ob_start`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) (and friends) to capture that output and emit it after the header has been sent:

```
ob_start();
// ...
$QString = '';
foreach($XMLItems as $key => $value)
{
   $QString .= $key.'^'.$value.'|';
}
$QString = substr($QString,0,-1);
Redirect('XMLProcess.php?Q='.$QString);

function Redirect($n)
{
    header("Location: $n");
    $contents = ob_get_clean();
    // echo $contents; // if you want or need to
    // you might also consider leaving this, but clients will
    // honor the 302 before executing any Javascript
    die("<script type=\"text/javascript\">window.location='$n';</script>");
}
```

All of this said, though, the code is feeling pretty janky. If at all possible, consider refactoring the HTML and XML versions so that the main work of the code is done in an included helper, and the HTML and XML "front-ends" just focus on rendering the output in the desired format.